# Can you activate the Protective Aura of a Rod of Alertness if the ground is too solid to be pierced?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

A [Rod of Alertness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/rod-of-alertness) has the Protective Aura property, which can be activated once per day by planting the half end of the rod in the ground.

But what if you're in an area where the ground is too solid to be pierced, such as a floor of obsidian? Can you still use the Protective Aura property in this case (making the Rod stand vertically or something), or no?

Comment: *But what if you're in an area where the ground is too solid to be pierced, such as a floor of obsidian?* Which property is more important to you: that the ground be too solid to be pierced, or that it be made of Obsidian? Obsidian is more brittle than you may be aware, and unless it's been enchanted, it's not going to fulfill your "too solid to be pierced" criterion.

Comment: Heh, bad example then. Ehhh, brick ?

Comment: I don't think the exact material matters here, what matters is that it is un-piercable. It could be a wall of force if you really want to find an example.

Answer (score 9):

## By a *very strict* RAW reading (possibly overly strict), you probably wouldn't be able to activate this feature

If the ground cannot be pierced, then you'd be unable to "plant the rod in the ground", per the requirements of the Magic Item.

It's not clarified by the item description whether this requirement is about drawing power out of the ground, a'la *"Drawing on the natural power of the Earth"*, or if it's just a matter of keeping the rod upright. In the latter case, a DM would probably permit you to simply prop it up with a stand or some other object. In the former case, probably not.

Ultimately, you'll have to ask your DM how they would rule in this situation. The fact that this technicality could result in a relatively powerful magic item being unable to use its signature feature may be enough to persuade them to make an exception, or at least give you a work-around. On the other hand, sometimes it's okay to have situations where a magic item just won't work.

From my perspective, it's probably okay to just let the rod be propped up by a stand or some other object. But that's not guaranteed to be your DM's perspective.

Comment: Wedge it in a crack? It feels like the restriction is to stop it being used inside a man-made structure type dungeon.

Comment: You could argue that the rules let you plant it in the ground regardless of what it's made of, so long as it's 'ground' and not 'floor' because the spell text says you can. Specific beats general, after all, and the Spell Text says 'plant it in the ground', which is more specific than 'Obsidian is hard'

Comment: @MarkTO I don't think this interpretation is right. For example, Acid description says "you can splash the contents" and I'm pretty sure it does not override things like being tied.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes.

Specific beats general, and the spell text 'Plant it in the ground' supersedes the much more general durability of any substance whatsoever. However, it must be 'ground' and not 'floor' which means it won't work on the roof of a castle, for example.